# How to install a specific version of node in a Ubuntu environment

Tags: wordpress, docker, ubuntu, nvm

When I `docker run -it wordpress:php7.0-apache` I could execute all of those following command

```
FROM wordpress:php7.0-apache
RUN apt-get update
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
RUN /bin/dash ~/.profile
RUN /bin/dash nvm install 8.11.4
```

My issue is when I try to `docker build -t imageName:version` I would have  an error : 
`/bin/dash: 0: Can't open nvm
The command '/bin/sh -c /bin/dash nvm install 8.11.4' returned a non-zero code: 1277`

What could be the difference ?

Comment: In a Docker context I wouldn't bother using a tool that allows multiple concurrent versions of some language runtime; just install the specific version you're going to use, or better still, do one thing in one image (don't install Node in a PHP image) and start from something like the [node](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) prebuilt image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you David Maze. Indeed there is no need of nvm to install a specific version.
My Dockerfile now :

```
FROM wordpress:php7.0-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg gnupg2 gnupg1
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
```